# OpenTK CreatePerspective Matrix Not Behaving Properly

Tags: c#, opengl, visual-studio-2017, opentk

I am trying to move my game engine from Java with LWJGL 3 to C# with OpenTK (OpenGL 3+). So far I can draw a triangle with a texture. However, when I try to upload the projection matrix to the shader, it doesnt work. Here are the things I tried:

-Upload uniform float to shader - Works
-Upload only identity matrix without perspective - WORKS
-Don't multiply vertex by projection - Works
-Create projection manually - Doesn't Work

Here is the code:

```
//At the top of class
Matrix4 projection;

//In render method
projection = Matrix4.Identity;
projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 4,
            1280 / 720, 1f, 100f);

int loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(progId, "projection");
GL.UniformMatrix4(loc, false, ref projection);
//Other render stuff
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;

out vec2 frag_uv;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    frag_uv = uv;
}
```

As I said, I think uniforms are uploaded correctly because when I delete the CreatePerspectiveFOV method, the triangle appears again. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Which are your vertices coordinates? Do you use a *View Matrix*?

Comment: No, it is only a projection matrix without a view, the vertex coordinates have a -2 as a z-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK stores its matrices in row-major order, not column-major like most other matrix libraries. This means you have to change up your multiplication order, because matrix multiplication is order-dependent, unlike scalar multiplication.

There are two ways you can fix this:

- In your call to `GL.UniformMatrix4`, pass `true` instead of `false`. This will transpose your matrices so that they're in column-major format.
- In your vertex shader, swap the order you multiply your matrix/vector, so that it's `vec4(pos, 1.0) * projection;`.

Either one should work.